# Changing a method name dynamically in a loop?

Tags: python-3.x, function, loops, methods

I am actually struggling while trying to change a method name within a loop. I am building a GUI with QT and I am facing the problem of repeating the same function but with a different name.

Here is my code:

```
from Config import Ui_Dialog

class Ui_Dialog_Useful(Ui_Dialog):

    def setupUi(self, widget):
        super().setupUi(widget)
        self.Sensitivity_filler()

    def Sensitivity_filler(self):
        self.Sensitivity_1.insertItems(0, ['10', '100', '1000'])
        self.Sensitivity_2.insertItems(0, ['10', '100', '1000'])
        self.Sensitivity_3.insertItems(0, ['10', '100', '1000'])
        self.Sensitivity_4.insertItems(0, ['10', '100', '1000'])
        self.Sensitivity_5.insertItems(0, ['10', '100', '1000'])
        self.Sensitivity_6.insertItems(0, ['10', '100', '1000'])
        self.Sensitivity_7.insertItems(0, ['10', '100', '1000'])
        self.Sensitivity_8.insertItems(0, ['10', '100', '1000'])
```

As you can see the only change between the functions is the name of the QComboBox object. I have to perform this several times. Is there a way to do that within a loop?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you shouldn't be doing this (i.e. dynamic names, since collections do this better), but since UI code tends to be tricky, you can use `getattr` to get the right object.

For example, you'd probably do:

```
for i in range(1, 9):
    getattr(self, 'Sensitivity_'+str(i)).insertItems(0, ['10', '100', '1000'])
```

If there's a way of doing this without using `getattr`, you should definitely use it. I'm not familiar with QT by any means. For example, if it's possible, you should be storing your sensitivity items as an iterable (i.e. `self.sensitivities`) and iterating over that instead.

Comment: +1 for following your "Don't do this" with a "Here's how to do it in case you want to ignore good practice." Way too many answers leave out the second half.

Comment: This totally worked for me. I am going to follow your advice and try to build an interable. Thank you so much.